# The velocity of electricity (electromagnetic waves) in a cable depends in the cable lenght or in the spatial distance of the measurments?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

The propagation velocity of an electromagnetic wave in a cable, depends on the cable lenght (like traveling through the cable) or in the distance between the measurments (like speed of causality)?

Comment: clarifications. 1) fibre optic cable (electicity is not EM wave). 2) what measurements exactly?

Comment: Why would the velocity depend on the cable length or on a distance between measurements? It is a property of the cable which comes from its properties like the material used for the cable etc.

Comment: Check this out: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/358894/speed-of-light-vs-speed-of-electricity/358900#358900

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking speed depends on the properties of the cable, mainly its refractive index. In fibre optics refractive index can vary with radius, helping signals to traverse curves.
The distance over which the velocity is measured is not relevant in the general case.