# Speed of a current passing through a wire

Tags: electricity, speed-of-light, electric-current

The wire is at 50hz, and is an aluminum alloy (AAAC 1120). Resistance in the wire is at 0.0897 ohm/km. So for a length of conductor 135km long, the resultant resistance will be 12.1095 ohm. It's AC current at about 220 KV. Other data about the wire can be found [here](https://www.olex.com.au/eservice/Australia-en_AU/navigateproduct_540272675/Type_AAAC_1120.html#characteristics). The line will be carrying roughly 15 MW of current.

How fast (in any measurement, but in an actual number) would the current move through the wire? I know about electron drift already, what I need to know is how fast it would travel through a wire with those specs, so if a pulse starts/stops how long it takes for this change to reach the other point 135 km downstream.

Edit: have checked possible duplicates, and while they do cover the same matter, i'm looking for a number or a fraction. While I know it's a fairly high portion of the speed of light, it's not an actual number. Some say 2/3, some say 1/10, some say 8/10, and when you deal with almost 300000km/s it's a large difference. They all say it depends on the wire, and aluminum alloy wire for large amounts of current is no doubt very different to standard copper.

Comment: Also of interest: [Speed of light vs speed of electricity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/358894/speed-of-light-vs-speed-of-electricity)

Comment: The formula you reference in wikipedia does not refer to the speed of waves travelling along the conductor, but instead refers to speed of the wavecrests as a wave decays evanescently from a  surface of the conductor into its bulk. The equation describing this is a diffusion equation rather than a wave equation.